# servicio de windows para ejecutar queries de sql server

Tags: sql-server, servicio

Tengo un problema la cual es que no puedo ejecutar un query dentro de un servicio de windows. Recurro a un  servicio por que necesito ejecutar un query a una determinada hora del día, el resultado de la consulta será enviada por correo al usuario que le corresponde, he depurado el código dentro de una aplicación de consola, windows forms y todo OK, pero en un servicio, en el punto donde se da la conexión al servidor y ejecutar el query no sucede nada, no me arroja error ni nada. Alguna idea de que pueda ser o simplemente no se posible consumir o escribir a una BD desde un servicio Windows.

He estado depurando y al parecer el error esta en la linea

```
sda.Fill(customersSet)
```

Gracias

```
Public t1 As New Timers.Timer

Public Sub New()

    ' Esta llamada es exigida por el diseñador.
    InitializeComponent()

    t1 = New Timers.Timer
    AddHandler t1.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf Me.ValidaFechasAEnviar)

    t1.Interval = 10000

End Sub

Private Sub ValidaFechasAEnviar()
    Dim oldDate As Date
    Dim oldWeekDayName As String
    oldDate = DateTime.Now '#2/12/1969#
    oldWeekDayName = WeekdayName(Weekday(oldDate))

    Dim ultimo As String = File.ReadLines("D:\Prueba_LOG\Registro_Envios.log").Last


    If oldWeekDayName.ToUpper = "LUNES" Or oldWeekDayName.ToUpper = "JUEVES" Or oldWeekDayName.ToUpper = "MARTES" Then

        If Date.Now.ToShortDateString.Trim.Equals(ultimo.Substring(0, 10).Trim) Then

        Else

            If DateTime.Now.Hour = 0 Then

                obtDatUsuarios()

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub obtDatUsuarios()

    Dim customersSet As DataSet = New DataSet()

    Dim customersTable As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select p.NomUsuario,  p.EMail from PagosReplicaAlerta p where  p.NomUsuario IS NOT NULL group by p.NomUsuario, p.EMail", "Data Source=(Local);Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Bd;")

    sda.Fill(customersSet)


    Dim usu As String = ""
    Dim mail As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To customersSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        usu = customersSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)
        mail = customersSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
        lstDatosUsuarios.Add(New Ejecutivos(usu, mail))
    Next

    Dim cont As Integer = 0
    Dim txt As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstDatosUsuarios.Count - 1

        txt &= enviarCorreo(lstDatosUsuarios.Item(i).NomUsuario, lstDatosUsuarios.Item(i).EMail).ToString & " "

        cont += 1

    Next

    WriteBN("[" & cont & " correos enviados (" & txt.Trim & ")]")
    lstDatosUsuarios.Clear()
End Sub
```

Comment: Te faltaria mostrar como tenes agregado el servicio de windows, si sabes que esta activo, podrias tambien hacer un log para ver que sucede en tu servicio.

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone, he probado creando el servicio de dos formas, la primera es creando un proyecto solución desde visual estudio la cual este crea un instalador y listo. viendo que no funcionaba cree un .exe (aplicación de consola) y un servicio manualmente y tampoco funcionaba. OJO, el servicio si levanta y se mantiene en ejecución siempre, al depurar linea por linea al llegar a la linea de conexión se detiene y no me arroja error en ese punto. ¿Alguna idea de que podría suceder?

Comment: ok, pero como Servicio de Windows a mi entendimiento deberia estar alojado en los servicios de windows.

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone, no entiendo cuando me indicas que debe estar alojado en los servicios de windows.

Comment: mira este documento para que entiendas mejor -> https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications

Comment: Ya estoy por tirar la toalla con el servicio de windows para consumir de una BD. Que otra opción o método me recomiendan para ejecutar un query a una determinada hora. @RamiroBarone

Comment: hoy veo de hacer un ejemplo de sericio de windows. Pero la idea siempre es que vos pongas tu codigo y se vea donde falla.

Comment: Coloca el codigo que realizaste para mirarlo, y con servicio de windows, que hiciste exactamente?

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone, al parecer el error se presenta en sda.Fill(customersSet), no se por que, será que esta forma no es valida en servicios (ver lineas arriba).

Comment: Fijate la respuesta de Roger, que es lo mismo que te iba a decir, pero primero viendo el codigo y queria estar seguro que con Servicio de windows los dos hablamos de un proyecto de Servicio de Windows y lo instalaste en los servicios de windows y hubieras chequeado que el servicio se estuviera ejecutando.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente el problema venga determinado por un problema de permisos de usuario:

La cadena de conexión ("`Data Source=(Local);Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Bd;`") dice que es el usuario que ejecuta la aplicación (servicio) el encargado de conectarse. Si este usuario no tiene permisos, fallará.

Los servicios de windows típicamente se ejecuntan con usuarios del tipo "Servicio Local", "Servicio de Red", que poco tienen que ver con la base de datos. O bien damos permiso a la base de datos al usuario o bien cambiamos la cadena de conexión para que se conecte mediante un usuario propio de la base de datos, en vez de con seguridad integrada.

Comment: Hola, si tenias razón, cambie el tipo de conexión por el de  "Autenticacion de SQL Server". Gracias